# java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col 16 failed

Tags: android, database

My app is working fine but when we upgrade it the 1st time it shows error that we have get in Stack traces in google play.

**My Code:**

```
public Cursor getContentData(String pc, String sc) {

        return database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM content where pc=" + pc
                + " and sc=" + sc + "", null);
    }
```

**Error**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1027)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col 16 failed
at android.database.CursorWindow.getString_native(Native Method)
at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:369)
at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:49)
at com.zengamedia.parser.LoadLiveData.doInBackground(LoadLiveData.java:68)
at com.zengamedia.parser.LoadLiveData.doInBackground(LoadLiveData.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
```

Comment: did you change the schema of your DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your Error Says Below Line :

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0
>   col 16 failed

probably **The 17th column is some how missing in your DB query** statement.